# spork-testunit fails  with mocha

Tags: spork

I found that spork-test unit fail with mocha mock/stub. 
However, if I run the same test without spork, it works fine and all test passes.

It gives an error like the following.

```
 1) Failure:
....
not all expectations were satisfied
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<AnyInstance:User(id: integer, ...
```

Has anyone have the same experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.simonmathieu.com/post/9640016407/rails-spork-test-unit-mocha

it seems not going well each other, but i will give it a try on this.